# Doctorate in Medical Informatics

Tags: statistics, health-informatics, data

I am a scientific employee at a medical faculty. I administer and develop data capturing tools for medical studies and I want to get my doctorate. I want to build a data sharing platform, where institutes (like at a medical faculty) can "digitize" their studies at their site and make data sharing possible. Studies at universities are often just in excel files and lay there on individual PCs. So making it possible to consolidate the data, preparing it, putting it in a SQL data base and making it sharable, so a data seeker can start and work with the data, would be my main focus. So from emailing "Can I work with your data?" to an institute's study catalogue (Findable), managing the correspondence and granting access (Accessible), providing an API (Interoperable) and making a protocol which packages etc. where used to make it reusable (Reusable) = FAIR.

"Just" developing such a platform would not be enough, so I thought of the following:

1. Make it FAIR and define requirements, so my system meets the FAIR
   principles (Findable, Accessible, Interoperable, Reusable)
2. Close gaps that other tools do not - E.g. focus on an "On site"
   approach and not "a cloud solution", where an institute has to
   upload their sensitive data". Their data stays at their site.
3. Development of a prototype that controls the process and ensures
   data protection so that medical data does not leave the institute
4. Evaluate it on the basis of evaluation criteria (does it make data
   sharing possible etc)

At a medical faculty, do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to get an idea how this site works. You're asking for opinions, and opinion-based questions are off-topic here. This is a Q&A site where questions are expected to be answerable with factual answers, not a discussion site as you may be more accustomed to. So unless you can [edit] this into such a question, I'm afraid it may be closed.

Comment: Hi. If you have questions for a PhD, https://academia.stackexchange.com will be a much better place to ask them. A very broad answer is: yes, there are people who have had a similar topic as you mention for their PhD. However, given the very practical engineering aspect of the topic, you need to find a place where this topic will be well-received and where you will be able to do more grounded-in-reality work than just write abstract theories about possible database systems. So you need to find a supervisor which is really interested and invested in this topic.

Comment: This question isn't about medical sciences. It's about building a program(?)/tool. Or as Dr. McCoy (of Star Trek fame) would say, "Dammit, Jim, I'm a doctor, not a data sharing platform builder!"

Comment: Generally your description is not at all how it will work. Data is usually tightly protected for a number of reasons, not least of which is commercial sensitivity, as well as patient protection, and publication rights, etc. You usually have to have legal agreements with the institute to access the data and sharing takes place after that. Data is also bound by grant funding - you usually have to be in collaboration to access the data otherwise you're trying to get free access to research that someone else has paid for! Big collabs already have these sorts of things in place - GISAID is one.

Comment: I agree with what has been said here about your question being opinion-based. But I also feel that Bryan's response to your other question was a bit harsh. Nonetheless, what you are describing has been implemented and is used in a number of academic medical centers. For example, see the [OMOP Common Data Model](https://ohdsi.github.io/CommonDataModel/). I don't think there's any chance that a single PhD student is going to do what multi-million dollar projects can't. Much more likely to find a PI involved in an existing project and try to improve rather than reinvent.

Comment: Hi! Thx! yes, data protection is an issue and yes, also the funding. Our institute owns a lot of data with many clinics and it is also the clinics that want this tool. The clinic's phd students and other researchers want that tool to build models and also want to share their code with others (to some degree). With my questions here I wanted to put this pressure on me because I need the critic to be more precise. it is not just a data sharing but also a modelling platform, where researchers can work with simulated data and the PI applies it on our real data comfortably by just clicking a button

Comment: Ian's probably right and my commentary was a bit harsh, but I do think you need quite a reset in your thinking and I'm worried if you don't you're going to waste a lot of your time. As someone who's professional job is to analyze data, I have to say that "where researchers can work with simulated data and the PI applies it on our real data comfortably by just clicking a button" is a bit offensive/scary. I'm quite familiar with some very specialized research tools in my field where people attempted something like this... The result is papers where the authors have no idea what they did.

Comment: That means that they announce conclusions that are not actually supported by their data, rather, they were fooled into thinking those conclusions were accurate because the simple tool they used told them so. The assumptions made by the person creating the tool were not the same as the assumptions made by people using the tool later, and because the tool made it "easy" they never bothered to learn what was actually happening. Medical data is really terrible for these sorts of things... Even when recorded as part of a planned trial, data are messy.

Comment: When you get into medical records and other sources of medical data that are not part of a specific plan, it gets far worse. If you strip out all identifiers (leaving aside the question of whether this is even possible or whether records are still identifiable, especially by people who might have additional supporting data that is private to them), you may be left with a situation where people analyzing the data cannot know which observations are repeats. I've analyzed hospitalization data where hundreds of individual visits were the same person.

Comment: appreciated. but...in Germany the law is very strict about data protection and things like trust centers are p in the a for quite some universities. Working with clinical data is a struggle and the chaos is present. There are good clinicians but in all the projects I am in I observe that 98% (guessed) don't really care about variables and so don't think about analysis. The current data sharing platforms are not really good in terms of standardization and yet no one has found a very nice way to make data sharing possible. I looked at many platforms and only the industries make ok approaches.